# Having trouble while installing face_recognition using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, face-recognition

I tried to install face_recognition package using **"conda install face_recognition -c conda-forge face_recognition"**

and bumped into the following error:

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- face_recognition

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

-https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64

-https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noah

-https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64

-https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64

-https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64

-https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64

-https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch

can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The package that you are trying to install [is only able using pip](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#installation-options), using the command `pip install face_recognition`.

I know it's a problem to install some packages using pip and others using conda, but you can always request the addition of the package to conda index...

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following command instead of conda commands.

```
pip install face-recognition
```

since conda environment also supports the pip packages, we can use pip to install.

and before installling the face_recognition library , make sure that you  have installed cmake and dlib